# How can I add a plugin in Phonegap project?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a need to add plugin in my Android phonegap app, but I have not found anything to start. Can anyone give me any clue?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS579US579&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=add%20a%20plugin%20to%20a%20phonegap%20project :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask.

Comment: OP, can you give us a little more detail? Your question is quite vague/general. Being more specific will help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not explored phonegap site properly. Check this link - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface.

Comment: thanks I don't know how I missed this..!! :(